# Retrieving json specific property?

Tags: javascript, json, api

I am using a news API to retrieve news from different from us from different news sources. The API call is successful but retrieving the information in loop and population an `HTML` page with it isn't working. For example, in the news API if I try to retrieve the description of the news and populate an `HTML` page with it in a loop it gives me back an undefined error.

This code works for one of the articles at a time but retrieving all of them in a for loop doesn't.
`var allArticles =parsedData.articles[0].description;console.log(allArticles);`

```
`var request = new XMLHttpRequest;

request.open('GET','https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines? 
country=us&apiKey=5060977c4cef473e8e06cb2ad53ea674')

request.onload = function(){
var response = request.response
var parsedData = JSON.parse(response)
console.log(parsedData)

for(var item in parsedData)
{
    //create a title for the news
    var allArticles = parsedData.articles[item].description;
    console.log(allArticles);

    //create the element on html
    var titleElement = document.createElement('p');


    titleElement.innerHTML = allArticles;

    //place it inside the body
    document.body.appendChild(titleElement)
}
}

request.onerror = function(){
console.log("There appears to be problem accessing the API")
}
request.send();`
```

Error code display in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'description' of undefined
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onload
```

Comment: `for(var item in parsedData)` You're iterating over `parsedData`, not `parsedData.articles` here

Comment: Do a line by line debugging by breakpoints and you can solve this and many problems by ownself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(var item in parsedData.articles)
{
    //create a title for the news
    var allArticles =item.description;
    console.log(allArticles);

    //create the element on html
    var titleElement = document.createElement('p');


    titleElement.innerHTML = allArticles;

    //place it inside the body
    document.body.appendChild(titleElement)
}
```

Comment: I see, I tried it and it works.  I thought that I would have to iterate over the parsedData then to later iterate over the parsedData.articles. It didn't occur to me that I could it in one go.

Answer (score 0):

Make the following change and it will work:

```
for(var i;i<=parsedData.length;i++)
{
    //create a title for the news
    var allArticles = parsedData.articles[i].description;
    console.log(allArticles);

    //create the element on html
    var titleElement = document.createElement('p');


    titleElement.innerHTML = allArticles;

    //place it inside the body
    document.body.appendChild(titleElement)
}
```